# Spring boot heroku "No web processes running"

Tags: heroku, spring-boot

I´m currently working on a Spring Boot application that is deployed in heroku. The application has 2 main projects on the same repo (frontend and backend). I`ve managed to get running the frontend using node.js and (technically) also managed to get running the spring boot application.

```
    2017-03-16T08:17:14.834886+00:00 app[api.1]: 2017-03-16 08:17:14.834  INFO 4 --- [main] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet: FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 35 ms
    2017-03-16T08:17:14.906139+00:00 app[api.1]: 2017-03-16 08:17:14.905  INFO 4 --- [main] com.zilicio.editor.ServerApplication: Started ServerApplication in 14.331 seconds (JVM running for 16.638)
    2017-03-16T08:17:14.881330+00:00 app[api.1]: 2017-03-16 08:17:14.881  INFO 4 --- [main] .s.b.c.e.j.JettyEmbeddedServletContainer: Jetty started on port(s) 11831 (http/1.1)
```

Everything seems ok according to that logs, but when I access the application it return an HTTP 500 claiming that there are no Web process running.

```
    2017-03-16T08:17:29.435087+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/api/projects" (...)
```

But when I check with heroku ps

```
    api.1: up 2017/03/16 03:16:56 -0500 (~ 30m ago)
```

This is my procfile:

```
    web: node Z-Editor/Frontend/server.js
    api: java -Dserver.port=$PORT $JAVA_OPTS -jar Z-Editor/Server/target/*.jar
```

It declares the 2 process (one for the front and one for the server). There are 2 different heroku apps running each one of the dynos. The node.js dyno is working but the one with Spring boot is not.

This is the folder structure of the repo:

```
    +root
      - procfile
      + frontend
         - package.json
         - ...
      + server
         - src
         - pom.xml
         + target
            - server.jar
            - ...
      - package.json
```

Hope someone can help me.

PD: The package.json and pom.xml in the root folder are the same as the ones in frontend and server folders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sure about your exact setup, but in general you can have only one process that will receive http requests. And this process must be named `web`. In your case, `web` process is your node application. `api` process can run fine, but it will never get any request. You need to split those two processes in two separate Heroku apps.

Comment: Thanks. you are right, the web process is the one that receives the http requests. I have 2 different apps, but there´s one repo that contains both. it is possible to have 2 procfile files and specify which one applies for each app ?

Comment: You can create an additional script that will run either your node app or spring app depending on some env variable, for example `APP_TYPE`. In your Procfile just run this script as web process. I think it should work. Another solution would be to create simple buildpack that will create appropriate Procfile during build, but it is more complicated solution.